# Converting 3d points to 2d points in c# windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, 3d, 2d

I am currently taking a course on basics of computer graphics and in this task I am asked to construct a 3d object(e.g a cylinder), I am currently studying an example but I am stuck on the code fragment that converts from 3d to 2d. I can't find any mathematical explanation of the formula being used and I will like to understand how the fragment works,

Here is the  code fragment that converts

```
  private Point Convert_3D_To_2D_Point(Point3D point)
    {
        double xPoint = -point._z * Math.Sin(3.14) + point._x * Math.Cos(3.14) + centre.X;
        double yPoint = -(point._z * System.Math.Cos(3.14) + point._x * System.Math.Sin(3.14)) * System.Math.Sin(1.0) + point._y * System.Math.Cos(1.0) + centre.Y;
        return new Point((int)(xPoint), (int)(yPoint));
    }
```

I figured out a 4 * 4 matrix from this function

```
    Cos A         0             -sin A          x0
-SinA * SinB    -CosB           -Cos(A)         y0
      0           0               0             0
      0           0               0             1
```

This matrix wasn't part of the different projection matrices we studied in the class and I'm having trouble finding such a transformation matrix online
I will like to know how the matrix works, what I can study to have a full understanding of what's going on.

Comment: this looks like the product of a translation matrix and rotation matrix

Comment: Does this answer your question? [3d to 2d point conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15079764/3d-to-2d-point-conversion)