# Drawing 3D Orthographic On Screen

Tags: java, 3d, cube, orthographic

so for the project I'm working on, I have a Cube class that saves the vertices of a cube. It saves the X, Y, and Z values. I need a way to draw these points on a 2D screen. (In terms of X and Y) orthographically. I've looked at Wikipedia's page about 3D projections but was left confused. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Note: I'm doing this I'm Java but could relatively easily transfer source code from other languages.

Comment: this questions seems already be answered...

maybe you take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15844101/projection-transforming-3d-to-2d